# Excel - How to compare one cell with values from two columns to return the index of the row that satisfies the equation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these columns:

```
H           I           J
q_i(t)      q_i-1(t)    r_k
0,042686                0,44
0,122656    0,042686    0,96
0,173631    0,122656    0,90
0,209514    0,173631    0,58
0,264281    0,209514    0,37
0,320746    0,264281    0,17
0,373511    0,320746    0,37
0,401536    0,373511    0,55
0,458303    0,401536    0,01
0,506941    0,458303    0,87
0,547891    0,506941    0,59
0,571245    0,547891    0,75
0,630292    0,571245    0,29
0,73077     0,630292    0,11
0,749792    0,73077     0,08
0,813533    0,749792    0,93
0,848933    0,813533    0,35
0,888867    0,848933    0,77
0,924318    0,888867    0,85
1           0,924318    0,28
```

For each r_k I want to find a row index that satisfies this equation: q_i-1(t)<r_k<=q_i(t). So I want for each row from column J to check the equations for all rows from columns H and I. An example result would look like this:
r_k = 0.44 so I get the index of row in column H that contains 0.458303 because 0.401536 < 0.44 <= 0.458303. I don't know how to do something like this in excel. I have tried MATCH and IF formulas, but I get wrong results.

```
MATCH(TRUE;IF($I$4:$I$23<J4<=$H$4:$H$23;TRUE;FALSE);0)
```

I tried this formula for first value in J -> 0.44.

```
IF(I4:I23<J4<=H4:H23;TRUE;FALSE)
```

But it returned me this result:

```
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
```

It should be TRUE in one row.

Comment: You are dealing with rounding errors. Lookup in the Internet for "what every programmer should know about floating point"

Comment: @Tarik This wasn't a rounding error problem. I managed to solve it in the end, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the IF formula:

```
IF(I12<J4<=H12;TRUE;FALSE)
```

This gives me FALSE.

When I break this formula into two:

```
IF(I12<J4;TRUE;FALSE)
```

This gives me TRUE.

```
IF(J4<=H12;TRUE;FALSE)
```

And this gives me true.

When I combine this using AND:

```
IF(AND(I12<J4;J4<=H12);TRUE;FALSE)
```

It gives me TRUE. But I can't use it, because AND returns me one overall result, instead of result for each row separately.

So I managed to write something like this and it works:

```
MATCH(1;($I$4:$I$23<J4)*(J4<=$H$4:$H$23);0)
```

Comment: You can short the formula like `MATCH(1,($I$4:$I$23<J4)*(J4<=$H$4:$H$23),0)`.

Comment: And if you want to return TRUE/FALSE then use `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,($I$4:$I$23<J4)*(J4<=$H$4:$H$23),0))`.

Comment: Even if it is not the problem, you need to take this into account to avoid subtle errors. Tou can round LHS and RHS to the nearest 1E-5 for example.